# Lemmatize a tm corpus

Tags: r, nlp, lemmatization

I am trying to lemmatize a `VCorpus` using a custom dictionary, in particular [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brema76/lemmatization-ita/master/lemmatization_ita.csv) one I found on github. I have not been able to find a function that correctly performs this. I have tried the following:

```
lemma <- read.csv("~/lemma.txt")
corpus <- tm_map(corpus,lemmatize_strings, dictionary = lemma)
```

But with no luck.

The other solution I can come up with is to loop through every word and gsub it, but it seems quite inefficient.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [reprex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). No luck doesn't describe what is going on. It didn't word, returned errors, etc. etc..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.